# Can elasticsearch 6.3.x be run on a user other than elasticsearch on centos 7?

Tags: elasticsearch

Can elasticsearch 6.3.x be run on a user other than elasticsearch on centos 7? If yes how do I configure it.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_installation.html#_installation_example_with_tar
If you use this installation method, you can just give the ownership of the folder to any user you need

If you use RPM, then I suspect the answer is no - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295944/is-is-possible-to-override-an-rpms-service-user-account-during-installation